# Different styles for first result in drupal 7 Admin view results

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am working on Drupal 7 and have been configuring view which in result display 4 different rows.

I need to apply different css to fist result (image / title / summary) and then some another css to rest of results.

I have been trying to use Global:View result counter field but dont know where exactly we can apply split of css for first row result and rest of row.

Can any one help me or gv brief about it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create views attachment, display 1 result and attach before your main view. In main view pager settings skip first row.

Comment: What lamp5 suggests above is a poor way of doing it, as it will require another full sql query. Why not use the css [:first-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) selector? If you must change the html, the best way would be to override the template that is being used (in your view admin, under advanced, click "theme: information"). But really, just do it with css :first-child

Comment: Why not using a hook to alter markup attributes before rendering ? If I'm not wrong you can achieve it by implementing `hook_views_pre_render()`